# How to iterate code over each string in a list of strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a list of objects that I would like to check and extend.
Specifically, my initial dataframe is

```
Name        
1   object1 
7   object2 
6   object3 
4   object4 
0   object5 
8   object6
```

I apply the following function to my dataframe:

```
def example(file):
    
...
    my_list2 = []
    for u in file['Name']:

        try:
            minim = ...
        except:
            minim = 'NA'
        my_list2.append(minim)

    file['Others'] = my_list2
    return file
```

to create a new column, `Others`, that looks like:

```
    Name         Others
    1   object1 [object4, object3, object22]
    7   object2 [object1]
    6   object3 [object1]
...
```

What I would like to do is to apply the function also to each element in the lists in `Others` column. This means that I should run it for each variable in the first list, i.e.,

```
[object4, object3, object22]
```

in order to add to my initial dataframe one row (`object22`, since it is not included in `Name` column) and have something like this

```
    Name         Others
    1   object1 [object4, object3, object22]
    7   object2 [object1]
    6   object3 [object1]
...
   10   object22 [object23, object40, object1]
```

Of course, the loop stops to run when all the elements in `Others` are in the `Name` column.
`objectX` is just a dummy name for this example: the name of variables in `Name` could be `dog`, or `mom`, or whatever else.

I do not know how to run the function in order to apply it to the elements in the lists under the `Others` column, to append the results in the original dataset.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Summary:

I need to run the function

- for the objects in the column name. This generates a list of strings per each object (eventually, empty lists too);
- for each object in the list of strings: this creates new rows in Name column
- for the new objects added in the `Name` column

Comment: maybe you can provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question. In fact, I can't get what you really wanted clearly in the question.

Comment: @Ferris I updated the question. I do not know how to reduce the code in my function in order to make the example reproducible. You can think of the function as one which generates randomly a list of 'object' variables with suffix from 1 to 100 (just for make it simpler; but the variables in Name can be 'mom', 'dog', 'house', ...). Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks a lot

Comment: I post an answer for it, hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only to solve how to extract the new `Name` to handle.

you can use 'explode' to turn the list's elements to rows:

```py
data = [{'Name': 'object1', 'Others': ['object4', 'object3', 'object22']},
 {'Name': 'object2', 'Others': ['object1']},
 {'Name': 'object3', 'Others': ['object1']}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

          Name                        Others
    0  object1  [object4, object3, object22]
    1  object2                     [object1]
    2  object3                     [object1]

df_exp = df.explode('Others')
print(df_exp)

          Name    Others
    0  object1   object4
    0  object1   object3
    0  object1  object22
    1  object2   object1
    2  object3   object1

objn = pd.Series(list(set(df_exp['Others']) - set(df['Name'])), name='Name')
print(objn)

    0     object4
    1    object22
    Name: Name, dtype: object
```

then apply func to `objn` create `Others` content. Denote the new dataframe as `dfn`.

```
df = df.append(dfn)
```

repeat the explode and apply func until `len(objn) == 0`.