# How can I iterate until all entries are in a given column?

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I am trying to apply a while statement to my code in order to run it until all the elements in the lists below (in the column Check) are in column Source.

My code is as so far:

```
while set_condition: # to set the condition
     newCol = pd.Series(list(set(df['Check']) - set(df['Source']))) # this check for elements which are not currently included in the column Source
     newList1 = newCol.apply(lambda x: my_function(x)) # this function should generate the lists n Check -> this explains why I need to create a while statement
     df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(dict('Source'=newCol, 'Check'=newList1)), ignore_index=True) # append the results in the new column
     df = df.explode('Check')
```

I will give you an example of the process and of how `my_function` works: let's say that I have my initial dataset

```
Source       Check
mouse   [dog, horse, cat]   
horse   [mouse, elephant]   
tiger   []  
elephant [horse, bird]
```

After exploding `Check` column and appending the results to `Source`, I will have

```
Source       Check
mouse   [dog, horse, cat]   
horse   [mouse, elephant]   
tiger   []  
elephant [horse, bird]
dog     [] # this will be filled in after applying the function
cat     [] # this will be filled in after applying the function
bird    [] # this will be filled in after applying the function
```

Every elements in the lists should be added in Source column before applying the function.
When I apply the function, I populate the lists of the other elements; so, for example I can have

```
Source       Check
mouse   [dog, horse, cat]   
horse   [mouse, elephant]   
tiger   []  
elephant [horse, bird]
dog     [mouse, fish]  # they are filled in
cat     [mouse]
bird    [elephant, penguin]
fish    [dog]
```

Since `fish` and `penguin` are not in `Source`, I will need to run again the code in order to have the expected output (all the elements in the lists are already in the Source column):

```
Source       Check
mouse   [dog, horse, cat]   
horse   [mouse, elephant]   
tiger   []  
elephant [horse, bird]
dog     [mouse, fish] 
cat     [mouse]
bird    [elephant, penguin]
fish    [dog]
penguin [bird]
```

as both `dog` and `bird` are already in `Source`,  I will not need to apply again the function as all the lists are populated with elements already in the Source column. The code can stop to run.

What I would like to do is to stop the cycle/loop when all the elements in the lists are in the column Source and have applied the function to populate all the lists.

Thank you for all the help you will provide.

Comment: I don't understand your question. In the step "After applying the function, I will have for example", where does penguin come from? Why is dog associated with mouse and fish? It's hard to answer without knowing what you want to do.

Comment: @ApplePie it is very simple but I agree that I was not so clear ;) I have lists in Check columns. I would like to have all the elements (with no duplicates) in the Source column. The function my_function will generate every time I have new elements in Source their related lists in Check. I would like to run (then stop) the process until all the lists contain elements which are already in source. I have tried to explain a bit better in the post

Comment: it would help if you could provide a minimal reproducible input. thanks.

Comment: Hi Akshay, unfortunately I do not know how to summarise a function which generates randomly elements from the Source list, including new ones. You can think of numbers from 1 to 100 (let's say only odd in the Source column) and the function which randomly generates both odd and even in the lists in the Check column. Since in the Source column there are only odd numbers (let's say we have 5 rows) and the firsts lists contains both odd and even numbers, I would need to add the even numbers in the Source column. They would not have any list yet, as I had to re-apply the function to each of them.

Comment: Once applied the function to each row including the even numbers, I will have new lists with odd and/or even numbers. All the numbers that are not included yet in the Source column will need to be added. Then I should re-apply the function to generate new lists. I will need to stop the process when all the numbers in the lists are correctly added in the Source columns, and all with lists. I would like to help more, but I can only explain how the function works in order to make simpler what the loop should do. Sorry about that. Happy to answer all the questions that you might have

Comment: I hope this example may help a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838346/how-to-iterate-code-over-each-string-in-a-list-of-strings-in-pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are repeating the loop until there are no more rows to add to the DataFrame, that is the same as saying that all of the elements of `df['Check']` are found in `df['Source']`. You have to calculate that every loop anyway, so why not use it to break out of the loop?

```
while True: # loop forever!
     diff = set(df['Check']) - set(df['Source'])
     if len(diff) == 0:
         break # done!
     newCol = pd.Series(list(diff))
     newList1 = newCol.apply(lambda x: my_function(x))
     df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(dict('Source'=newCol, 'Check'=newList1)), ignore_index=True)
     df = df.explode('Check') # NOTE: I will use this to my advantage in the next suggested solution
```

Because [continually appending to a DataFrame is taxing on memory](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html?highlight=It%20is%20worth%20noting%20that#concatenating-objects), you might want to consider building the columns first, then building the DataFrame all at once outside of the loop. `df['Check']` is going to end up exploded anyway, so start by exploding and build onto those lists:

```
df = df.explode('Check')
check = df['Check']                # Append to this list as we iterate
source = df['Source']              # Append to this list as we iterate
unique_source = set(source)
diff = set(check) - unique_source  # Iterate until this is empty
while len(diff) > 0:
    new_check = [my_function(x) for x in diff] # a list of lists
    check.append(new_check)    # Add the list of lists as-is, but explode later
    source.append(diff)        # Keep track of the new sources for the DataFrame...
    unique_source.update(diff) # and keep track of the unique sources for efficiency
    flat_check = set(x for sublist in new_check for x in sublist)
    diff = flat_check - unique_source  # We only have to check the new elements!

df = pd.DataFrame({"Check": check, "Source": source}).explode("Check") # build the entire DataFrame at once
```

There are a lot of ways you can play with this structure to get the structure of the DataFrame you want. For instance, if you don't want to explode `df['Check']`, just keep around the original version of `df` at the beginning of this example and append the new data to that:

```
new_df = df.explode('Check')
unique_source = set(new_df['Source'])
diff = set(new_df['Check']) - unique_source
source = [] # append to empty lists
check = []  # append to empty lists
while len(diff) > 0:
    # ...

df = pd.append([df, pd.DataFrame({"Check": check, "Source": source})]) # keep the unexploded columns
```

Answer (score 0):

From What i roughly understand, I would say you can use the pandas .unique() to sort through each unique value in the lists, then use a for or while loop to check if the new unique value exists inside source column.

Comment: hi samar2170. I am having difficulties in writing the loop and check statements (this is the reason why I asked. It is ok for me how to set the problem and steps, but I do not know how to use properly the while (I think it would be the more appropriate) and the check of values from both columns in order to stop the function and getting the final results ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming data is being appended to arrays automatically, you could use:

```py
x = df['columnName'].values[-1]
for i in df['source']:
    if i == x:
        return(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially want is to stop when `newCol` is empty. Another way of phrasing this is that `set(df['Check'])` is a subset of `set(df['Source']`. So you want:

```
while ( set(df['Check']).issubset(set(df['Source']) == False ):
```